# PHP - Encryption of password between windows and ubuntu is different

Tags: php, windows, ubuntu-16.04

We have two servers running. An old `windows server 2008` and new `Ubuntu server 16.04.1`. My task is to match the encrypted password in the database and password type by the user. On the `Windows server` I tried to run my `source code` of encrypting password and it works, It matched. But trying to do run on `Ubuntu server` it returns characters like this `�����` so I can't matched the both password.
I've been looking for solution for days, Is this on server config? I run same code but the output is different between servers. Appreciate your help!

Code for encryption:

```
function fn_EncryptPassword() {
    $arg = func_get_args();

    foreach ($arg as $key => $args) {
        $_retval = '';
        $args=strtoupper(trim($args));
        for ($i=1; $i<=strlen($args); $i++) {
            $_retval.=chr(ord(substr($args,$i-1,1)) + 100);
        }
    }
    return $_retval;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using `password_hash()`?

Comment: A solution would probably be to automatically decrypt all passwords in your base and encrypt them using a better approach like `password_hash()`.
Your 'Caesar' like encoding algorithm is very weak. But at least you can retrieve the plain text passwords...
Finally you should not convert all passwords to upper case, that just make all the passwords weaker.

Comment: @NigelRen This code been used by the system a long time ago. It's been use for thousands of stored password and until now.

Comment: As Nigel said, now is a great time to make the switch to using `password_hash()` so the passwords really are protected. It will also solve the problem in the title of your question and, most likely, future proof too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function fn_EncryptPassword() {
    $arg = func_get_args();

    foreach ($arg as $key => $args) {
        $_retval = '';
        $args=strtoupper(trim($args));
        for ($i=1; $i<=strlen($args); $i++) {
            $_retval.=chr(ord(substr($args,$i-1,1)) + 100);
        }
    }
    return utf8_encode($_retval);
}



echo fn_EncryptPassword('şçogby*/');
```

add the utf_encode function